# Get announcements from Yammer

Tags: yammer

How would I go about pulling all announcements from Yammer through the REST api?

```
https://developer.yammer.com/docs/messagesjson
```

I know this REST endpoint pulls in the last 20 threads if I pass "threaded=true", however, what if an announcement was posted and is needed to be shown for a day, but since that time 25 new threads have popped up.

There must be a way to search by announcement type messages, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers